# How to uninstall laptop-mode-tools installed from an .tar.gz archive?

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, power-management

Hey all I downloaded this file (http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/laptop-mode-tools) but can't seem to be able to uninstall it. I tried looking online as well as the README file but there is only instruction for installing, not uninstalling the package.

Attempted solutions:

```
sudo apt-get remove laptop_mode
```

returned

```
E: Unable to locate package laptop_mode
```

but when I type in laptop_mode I do get

```
Unhandled kernel version: 3.13 ('uname -r' = '3.13.0-32-generic')
```

Is there any way I can uninstall laptop-mode-tools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have installed the DEB file eg. `laptop-mode-tools_1.52-1ubuntu2_all.deb`. The version is not decisive.

Therefore

```
sudo apt-get remove laptop-mode-tools
```

---

If you compiled it yourself from an archive. Goto the source folder and run

```
sudo make uninstall
```

---

If this not work, follow these steps:

1. Install `checkinstall`

   ```
    sudo apt-get install checkinstall
   ```
2. Go into the `laptop-mode-tools` source folder and compile the tools again
3. Start the installation with this command

   (The command installs a DEB package and replaces your previous installation)

   ```
    sudo checkinstall
   ```
4. Remove the package

   ```
    sudo apt-get remove laptop-mode-tools
   ```